# Упоминание духа сообщества в комментариях

Tags: обсуждение

Я тут иногда встречаю, что люди упоминают [@Духсообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) в своих комментариях, отвечая на его так скажем тревоги. Так вот, я знаю, что можно из очереди проверок отправить сообщение от имени духа сообщества

У меня вопрос такой: При выделении духа сообщества в комментариях, приходит ли уведомление тому, кто собственно написал сообщение от имени духа сообщества?

Для поиска использовал этот запрос:

```
Select PostId As [Post Link], Score, [Text], CreationDate From Comments
Where Lower([Text]) Like Lower(N'%##Text##%')
Order By Score Desc, CreationDate Desc
```

и в поле вбил: @Духсообщества

Comment: Не знаю, но мне кажется крайне маловероятным...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну значит не приходит, думаю за 7 лет тебе пришло бы хоть одно упоминание :) Надеюсь на то, что ты не забыл бы такое, если пришло :)

Comment: @EzioMercer фича отправки сообщений из очереди проверок появилась относительно недавно (вроде даже года ещё не прошло)

Comment: @EzioMercer, раньше коммент писался от имени пользователя. А потом решили, что хотят больше комментов и не вписываются в дневной лимит.

Comment: @andreymal Ну я это к примеру сказал, потому что сам этим пользовался, а так есть достаточно давние обращения. Но там они связаны с его деятельностью о поднятии вопросов и т.д. Это я так понимаю вообще никем (ну кроме алгоритмов) не контролируется

Comment: то есть, вместо того, что бы пофикисить лимиты, взяли и втулили это непотребство с духом? ох ох.

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал, что это сделали ради лимитов... Комменты от имени Духа != больше комментов